# Remove anything above 900 rows in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, sql-delete

This works in Mysql, but it seems that the syntax for MariaDB is different, I am trying to remove anything above the first 900 returned rows (LIMIT 900) :

```
DELETE FROM cronschedule NOT IN (SELECT * FROM cronschedule LIMIT 900);
```

Trying to do this in Maria though returns the following error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'NOT IN (SELECT * FROM cronschedule LIMIT 900)' at line 1
```

So how would I do this in Maria?

Comment: This syntax with `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT x)` doesn't work in MySQL either.

Comment: Plus, you missed the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect this to be a bit more efficient than your answer with the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` construction:

```
DELETE  cr.*
FROM    cronschedule cr
    JOIN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    cronschedule ii
        ORDER BY
                id ASC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 900
        ) i2
ON      cr.id >= i2.id ;
```

Comment: Accepting as a better way to do it than what I figured out, cheers. +1 to you and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
DELETE  cr.*
FROM    cronschedule cr
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    cronschedule ii
        ORDER BY
                id ASC
        LIMIT 900
        ) i2
ON      cr.id = i2.id
WHERE   i2.id IS NULL;
```